# Error Deploying Application in IIS with pass-through authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, webdeploy

When I deploy an asp.net application onto IIS, it shows me this message

```
The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.
```

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

How do I correct this?